# Buddypress membership

Tags: wordpress, membership, buddypress

I'm looking for a plugin that can do the following.
Support of different memberships (e.g. basic, silver, gold) including payment gateways with recurring payments.
Depending on the chosen membership option during registration (and later on upgrade) more fields shall appear in the registration form.
Those fields shall be displayed on the profile page of the user
I don't want to protect any content of the site. 
It is more to enhance the user profile with additional information depending on the subscription.

Comment: Google it? If not on google build yourself or hire someone.

Comment: wtf - i wanted first to understand if there is anything in this direction

Comment: You should ask on a more appropriate site then. This site is for coding issues you have tried to implement and need help with.

Answer (score 0):

I would use s2membership as this should solve your multiple membership issue.